# How to detect if a command, which is undefined in the current scope, also is undefined in all superordinate scopes?

Tags: grouping, scoping

Theoretical question/moot point:

Scenario: You wish to have defined a command globally. But you wish to have it defined only if it is undefined both in the current scope **and in all superordinate scopes**.

Question: Is there a strategy for doing this reliably?

Question: Can you reliably detect if a command, which is undefined in the current scope, also is undefined in all superordinate scopes?

This is a minimal example which does **not** do the trick:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\foo{This is foo's original definition}

\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\@ifundefined{foo}{\gdef\foo{This redefinition of foo is not applied.}}{}

\begingroup

\let\foo=\UndeFiNeD

\@ifundefined{foo}{\gdef\foo{This redefinition of foo was applied although foo was defined in a superordinate scope.}}{}

\endgroup

\show\foo

\end{document}
```

Terminal-output:

```
> \foo=macro:
->This redefinition of foo was applied although foo was defined in a superordin
ate scope..
l.32 \show\foo
```

Comment: in luatex you can look in the hash table which can give a hint (or possibly even a definitive answer, it's a while since I looked at the details)

Comment: You could do the definition locally, check the current group level and use `\aftergroup` if that is >0. In your `\aftergroup` code you check whether the macro is defined at this level, if so throw an error, else do the definition on this level locally and use `\aftergroup` if the nesting level is not yet 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In luatex you can do something similar and check if the command was ever defined, by looking in the hash table.

```
\documentclass{article}



\def\test#1{%
\directlua{
local tst = false
for i,v in pairs (tex.hashtokens()) do
if v=='foo' then tst=true end
end
if tst then
 print('\string\n#1:' .. 'DEFINED')
else
 print('\string\n#1:' .. 'UNDEFINED')
end
}
}


\test{A}

\newcommand\foo{This is foo's original definition}

\test{B}


\makeatletter

\begin{document}


\@ifundefined{foo}{\gdef\foo{This redefinition of foo is not applied.}}{}

\begingroup

\test{C}

\let\foo=\UndeFiNeD

\test{D}

\@ifundefined{foo}{\gdef\foo{This redefinition of foo was applied although foo was defined in a superordinate scope.}}{}

\endgroup

\test{E}

\show\foo

\let\foo\undefinedagain

\test{F}
\end{document}
```

But note the last entry F is still DEFINED, that is there is still a hash table entry for `\foo` even if it has been undefined at the top level.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a simple minded implementation of the idea in my comment.

We check whether the macro is defined. If it is we throw a warning that it is, ignoring the assignment. If it isn't we do the definition locally now, and create a global internal macro that we smuggle out of the current group with `\aftergroup`. In that macro we just call the original macro call again.

We can check whether we're at the first call of the macro by checking whether the global internal macro is defined or not. If this isn't the first call that internal will already be defined and we erroneously did the assignment, so now we throw an error (you might of course change this). Finally, if we reach the top-level we undefine our internal after doing the local definition a last time (provided the error case was never reached, in that case the internal will still be defined).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\globalnewassignment
  {
    \protected\def\globalnewassignment#1#2%
      {%
        \ifdefined#1%
          \ifx#1\relax
            \expandafter\@gobble
          \else
            \@ifundefined{globalnewassignment@@\detokenize{#1}}
              {%
                \PackageWarning{globalnewassignment}
                  {Macro \string#1 is already defined}%
              }%
              {%
                \PackageError{globalnewassignment}
                  {Macro \string#1 was already defined, now it's too late}{}%
              }%
          \fi
        \else
          \globalnewassignment@do#1{#2}%
        \fi
      }
  }
\protected\def\globalnewassignment@do#1#2%
  {%
    #2%
    \ifnum\currentgrouplevel>\z@
      \expandafter\xdef\csname globalnewassignment@@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
        {\unexpanded{\globalnewassignment#1{#2}}}%
      \expandafter
      \aftergroup\csname globalnewassignment@@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
    \else
      \global\expandafter\let
          \csname globalnewassignment@@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
          \globalnewassignment@undefined
    \fi
  }

\newcommand\foo{This is foo's original definition}

\begin{document}
\globalnewassignment\foo{\def\foo{This is a redefinition}}

\begingroup
\let\foo\UNDEFined
\globalnewassignment\foo{\def\foo{This is a redefinition}}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. +1 from me.  (But I suppose `\global` is not needed in case `\currentgrouplevel` is not > 0.)

Comment: @UlrichDiez yes, probably not, but it's a good habit to only do global assignments on a macro you do global assignments on :) Though the safestack is probably not that involved at `\currentgrouplevel=0` :)

Comment: yes I wondered about suggesting aftergroup originally, but worried whether that always shows up in a safe place (scars of afterpage having an effect on me. probably:-)

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{ll}
\globalnewassignment\foo{\def\foo{This is a redefinition}}
a
&
b
\end{tabular}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ouch :)

Answer (score 1):

If you rely on a flag-macro denoting the definition-status never being defined otherwise and never being touched and on `\globaldefs` having the value 0, and on macros in question being defined only in terms of `\DoOnlyIfUndefinedInAllscopes`, then you can do something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%

\newcommand\DoOnlyIfUndefinedInAllscopes[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \escapechar=-1 %
  \@ifundefined{definedflag@@\string#1@@WeirdPostfix}{%
    \@ifundefined{\string#1}{%
      \exchange{#2}%
    }{%
      %\GenericError{}{Control sequence \@backslashchar\string#1 already defined in the current scope}%
      %               {Action won't be performed if control sequence is already defined}{}%
      \@firstofone
    }%
    {%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
      \@namedef{definedflag@@\string#1@@WeirdPostfix}{defined}%
    }%
  }{%
    %\GenericError{}{Control sequence \@backslashchar\string#1 already defined in the current or some superordinate current scope}%
    %               {Action won't be performed if control sequence is already defined.}{}%
    \endgroup
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
%\DoOnlyIfUndefinedInAllscopes{\foo}{\gdef\foo{This is a definition}}
\DoOnlyIfUndefinedInAllscopes{\foo}{\def\foo{This is a definition}}
\message{^^JMessage 1: \string\foo: \meaning\foo}%

\begingroup
\let\foo\UNDEFined
\DoOnlyIfUndefinedInAllscopes{\foo}{\gdef\foo{This is a redefinition}}
\message{^^JMessage 2: \string\foo: \meaning\foo}%
\endgroup

\DoOnlyIfUndefinedInAllscopes{\foo}{\gdef\foo{This is another  definition}}
\message{^^JMessage 3: \string\foo: \meaning\foo}%
\endgroup

\DoOnlyIfUndefinedInAllscopes{\foo}{\gdef\foo{This is a definition after the group.}}
\message{^^JMessage 4: \string\foo: \meaning\foo}%

\end{document}
```

Terminal output:

```
Message 1: \foo: macro:->This is a definition 
Message 2: \foo: undefined 
Message 3: \foo: macro:->This is a definition

Message 4: \foo: macro:->This is a definition after the group.
```

The requirement of macros in question being defined only in terms of `\DoOnlyIfUndefinedInAllscopes` is the crucial point which limits the practical usability of this approach.
Therefore this approach does not really deserve upvotes.

Comment: Just a slight nagging: Why not use `\escapechar=\m@ne`? Also the `\relax` after the space after `-1` does essentially nothing (it doesn't stop the number expression, that's already done by the space) :)

Comment: @Skillmon I intended to remove the `\relax` but forgot about it during a sudden attack of pain. | `-1` instead of `\m@ne` is paranoia in the form of not relying on the meaning of `\m@ne`. (`-1` cannot be redefined but `\m@ne` can be redefined...) Be that as it may: The approach presented by me is not of much practical use as it is not of any help when it is about macros not necessarily defined using `\DoOnlyIfUndefinedInAllscopes`. | Being a nitpicker myself from time to time, I like your collaborative style of "nagging" because the focus is not on humiliation, but on improving code.